# Should stereo projection be internally consistent?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a problem where I have a calibrated stereo pair and am identifying stereo matches.  I then project those matches using `perspectiveTransform` to give me (x, y, z) coordinates.

Later, I'm taking those coordinates and reprojecting them into my original, unrectified image using `projectPoints` with takes my left camera's M and D parameters.  I was surprised to find that, despite all of this happening within the same calibration, the points do not project on the correct part of the image (they have about a 5 pixel offset, depending where they are in the image).  This offset seems to change with different calibrations.

My question is: should I expect this, or am I likely doing something wrong?  It seems like the calibration ought to be internally consistent.

Here's a screenshot of just a single point being remapped (drawn with the two lines):

[image: stereo]

(ignore the little boxes, those are something else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing something slightly wrong.  When reprojecting from 3D to 2D, I missed that `stereoRectify` returns `R1`, the output rectification rotation matrix.  When calling `projectPoints`, I needed to pass the *inverse* of that matrix as the second parameter (`rvec`).